# Parse.com Push Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud, jobs

I am trying to write a cloud code job for Parse that sends a push to everyone in a certain university once the university reaches 50 users. I'm pretty sure I wrote the code right but when I run the Job the push doesn't get sent. Any ideas?

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
Parse.Cloud.job("UniUsers", function(request, response) {
var query = new Parse.Query("Universities");
    query.notEqualTo("pushSent", "Yes");
    query.greaterThan("numUsers",49);
    query.first({
        success: function(uniObj){
            var uni = uniObj.get("university");
            var query2 = new Parse.Query("_User");
                query2.equalTo("university", uni);
                query2.limit(50);
                query2.find({
                    success:function(results){

                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
                            var object2 = results[i];
                            var userid = object2.id;
                                    var thePush = new Parse.Query("_Installation");
                                    thePush.equalTo('user',userid);
                                    Parse.Push.send({
                                    where: thePush,
                                    data:{
                                    aps:{
                                        alert: "Your University Has Been Unlocked! 
Start searching for your Roomie now!",
                                            sound: ""
                                                }
                                                }

                                            });

                            }
                            response.success("Success!");
                    },
                    error:function(error){
                        response.error("Error");
                                                }


                })
        }
    })




});
```

Comment: So one thing is that `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` should go into the job definition itself, also don't use string version _User as the classname, use the more future-proof `Parse.User` instead. Depending on the ACL you have set up, moving the masterkey into the job itself might already solve your issue.

Comment: Use console.log() to help in debugging.

Comment: You also might want to look into Parse Promises to help keep your code more understandable and reduce the indentation required.